# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } with unknow reason

Tags: javascript, php, html

I got an `Unexpected token }`, but I don't know why.

[image]

It is a table with some buttons on it. When the buttons is clicked, it will call the `Javascript` function.

Here is my code:

```
<tbody>
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($query as $row){?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address'] . ", " . $row['city'] . ", " . $row['state'] . ", " . $row['country']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <button id ="delete" class = "delete" type="button"  value=<?php echo "\"" . $row['id'] . "\""; ?> onClick="deleteAddress(this.value)">delete</button>
    </td>
    <td>
     //Print this <button id = "edit" class = "edit" type="button" value="7"  onClick = "editAddress( this.value, "23", "323", "323", "iij")" >Edit</button>
        <button id = "edit" class = "edit" type="button" value=<?php echo "\"" . $row['id'] . "\""; ?>  onClick = <?php echo "\"editAddress( this.value" . ", \"" . trim($row['address']) . "\", \"" . $row['city'] . "\", \"" . $row['state'] . "\", \"" . $row['country'] . "\")\""; ?> >Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
 function editAddress(id, address, city, state, country)
 {
     document.getElementById("address_field").value = address;
     document.getElementById("city_field").value = city;
     document.getElementById("state_field").value = state;
     document.getElementById("country_field").value = country;
     document.getElementById("add_new").innerHTML = 'Update Address';
     document.getElementById("add_new").value = id;
     document.getElementById("add_new").onclick = function() { 
        var id = document.getElementById("add_new").value;
        var address = document.getElementById("address_field").value; 
        var city = document.getElementById("city_field").value;
        var state = document.getElementById("state_field").value; 
        var country = document.getElementById("country_field").value;  

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../wp-content/plugins/add_address_list/insert_address.php",
            data: {functionName : "updateAddress", id : id, address : address, city : city, state : state, country : country},
            success: function(msg){
                window.location.reload();
            }
       }); 
    };
  }
```

The `IDE` don't have any syntax error. Don't know why.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the error coming from PHP or JavaScript, it's not really clear? You do have several syntax error, for instance `onClick = "editAddress( this.value, "23", "323", "323", "iij")"` won't work as you have doublequotes around the arguments at the same time as you're using doublequotes for the attribute.

Comment: Thx. Changed the doublequotes to singlequotes, then it is working now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There error is in:

```
onClick = "editAddress( this.value, "23", "323", "323", "iij")"
```

Or rather:

```
onClick = <?php echo "\"editAddress( this.value" . ", \"" . trim($row['address']) . "\", \"" . $row['city'] . "\", \"" . $row['state'] . "\", \"" . $row['country'] . "\")'"; ?> >Edit</button>
```

That should be:

```
<button id = "edit" class = "edit" type="button" value=<?php echo "\"" . $row['id'] . "\""; ?>  onClick ='<?php echo "editAddress( this.value" . ", \"" . trim($row['address']) . "\", \"" . $row['city'] . "\", \"" . $row['state'] . "\", \"" . $row['country'] . "\")"; ?> >Edit</button></td>
```

Just enclosing the JavaScript with `'` so double quotes are allowed so it would look like:

```
onClick = 'editAddress( this.value, "23", "323", "323", "iij")'
```

Comment: Changed the doublequotes to singlequotes, And it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Just forgot to Close your FOREACH Loop with "}" ;-)

just put

```
<?php } ?>
```

after the closing TR ... that should work.

Comment: I forgot to copy to here. LOL